# Component not re-rendering after setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component in my code:

```
class ContactsList extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         contactItems: [
            <ContactItem key="Lena" login="typeofweb1" name="Lena" department="JavaScript Developer" border="0" />,
            <ContactItem key="Brian" login="typeofweb2" name="Brian" department="Human Resources" />,
            <ContactItem key="Rick" login="typeofweb3" name="Rick" department="QA" />
         ]
      };
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <ul className="list-group list-group-flush container">
            {this.state.contactItems}
            <button type="button" onClick={this.addContactItem}>
               Add
            </button>
         </ul>
      );
   }

   addContactItem = () => {
      console.log(this.state.contactItems);
      this.state.contactItems.push(<ContactItem key="Rick" login="typeofweb3" name="Rick" department="QA" />);
      this.setState({ contactItems: this.state.contactItems });
   };
}
```

The problem is the fact that the component is not being updated, even tho the state is changing (I can see that in the console.log that the contactItems array is getting new elements). There is a problem with .push(), because if just change the setState to something like

```
this.setState({ contactItems: ["something"]});
```

then it works correctly.

Comment: standard mutate existing object problem

Comment: You are mutating your array. React needs to have a new array to know that props have changed

Comment: why you are push and updating state both at same time ??

Comment: How should I do this then?

   addContactItem = () => {
      this.newArray = this.state.contactItems;
      this.newArray.push(<ContactItem key="Rick" login="typeofweb3" name="Rick" department="QA" />);
      this.setState({ contactItems: this.newArray });
   };

This doesn't help

Comment: this is not new array, this way you're copying pointer to the same object. `var dup_array = original_array.slice();`

Answer (score 0):

I dont exactly know why, but this works:

```
class ContactsList extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         contactItems: [
            <ContactItem key="Lena" login="typeofweb1" name="Lena" department="JavaScript Developer" border="0" />,
            <ContactItem key="Brian" login="typeofweb2" name="Brian" department="Human Resources" />,
            <ContactItem key="Rick" login="typeofweb3" name="Rick" department="QA" />
         ]
      };
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <ul className="list-group list-group-flush container">
            {this.state.contactItems}
            <button type="button" onClick={this.addContactItem}>
               Add
            </button>
         </ul>
      );
   }

   addContactItem = () => {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
         contactItems: prevState.contactItems.concat([<ContactItem key="Rick" login="typeofweb3" name="Rick" department="QA" />])
      }));
   };
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the following code works and the previous does not?

Comment: Yes, it will work because there's no mutation now. Because you're using concat which is similar to my answer using spread operator.

Comment: Earlier I tried copying the array, and pushing to the new array, but it still didnt work, even tho I updated the state with new array and not with the currently located in state

Answer (score -1):

You should not mutate the state in react. You can use like this:

```
addContactItem = () => {
  this.setState({ contactItems: [
    ...this.state.contactItems, // clone the state,
    // then, add new item
    <ContactItem key="Rick" login="typeofweb3" name="Rick" department="QA" />
   ]
  });
};
```

Comment: when you need to calculate new state value based on some previous state value you should pass a callback function to `this.setState` method instead of directly reading from `this.state`. Otherwise the chances are to get not synced data. See more on official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate